# Replace CentralWidget in MainWindow

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyside

I'm kinda new to PySide.I have a main window object which shows one widget at a time. I've been trying to change the central widget of the `QMainWindow` class in order to replace the visible Widget in the window when pressing a button. The problem is that the button pressed is in the Widget class, not in the main window class.

say...

```
class App(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.statusBar().showMessage('Listo.') #Status Bar
        self.login_screen = LoginScreen()
        self.logged_in_screen = LoggedInScreen()

        self.setCentralWidget(self.login_screen)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 450, 600) #Window Size
        self.setWindowTitle('PyTransactio - Client') #Window Title
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon.png')) #App Icon
        self.show()
```

The pressed button is in the `login_screen` instance. The method called when the button is clicked is inside the `LoginScreen` class:

```
def login(self):
        """ Send login data to the server in order to log in """

        #Process

        self.setParent(None)
```

Setting the parent widget to `None` removes the widget (`login_screen`) from the main window. What should I do in order to get another widget (e.g. `logged_in_screen`) as the central widget of the main window when the `loginButton` (inside the `login_screen` widget) is pressed?

Maybe the login method should be inside the main window class? If so, how can I connect the buttons pressed in `login_screen` with the main window's method?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may use a [`QStackedWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html) as central widget and add both the log-in screen and "logged-in" screen to it.

An example usage:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.central_widget = QtGui.QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        login_widget = LoginWidget(self)
        login_widget.button.clicked.connect(self.login)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(login_widget)
    def login(self):
        logged_in_widget = LoggedWidget(self)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(logged_in_widget)
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(logged_in_widget)


class LoginWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoginWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Login')
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        # you might want to do self.button.click.connect(self.parent().login) here


class LoggedWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoggedWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel('logged in!')
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

If you do not want to use this widget, then I think you'll have to call `QMainWindow.setCentralWidget` every time you change the central widget.

As to where the `login` method should be, it depends. Probably you could define a simple interface for your mainwindow to add/remove/show specific central widgets, and call it from the `login` method of `LoginScreen`. In this way the `LoginScreen` class does not have to know about implementation details such as if the central widget is actually a `QStackedWidget` or this thing is done in an other way.

Comment: **QStackedWidget** did the thing. Also, I never thought about `self.parent().login`. Guess I'll have to work on my OOP. Thank you very much!

Comment: When setting as central widget, QMainWindow takes the ownership of that widget. When setting the other widget as central widget, the first one gets destroyed, which is bad.

Comment: @HrvojeT Yes, that's why my answer uses `QStackedWidget` and not that hack, which probably requires some ugly code to work properly.

Comment: Really great. using setCentralWidget didn't work for me, but this worked, because that solutions doesn't destroy the previous widgets.

Answer (score -3):

You can use QMainWindow.setCentralWidget to do this (repeatedly):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore

import sys 

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
mw = QtGui.QMainWindow()
w2 = QtGui.QWidget()
pb = QtGui.QPushButton('push me', w2) 

l1 = QtGui.QLabel('orig')
l2 = QtGui.QLabel('changed')
mw.setCentralWidget(l1)
pb.clicked.connect(lambda: mw.setCentralWidget(l2))
mw.show()
w2.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I know this is a possible workaround, but destryoing the last central_widget is a terrible side effect...

Comment: When you set an new central widget, the old one is destroy.