# Replacing the existing MainWindow with a new window with Python, PyQt, Qt Designer

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I'm new to Python GUI programming I'm have trouble making a GUI app. I have a main window with only a button widget on it. What i want to know is how to replace the existing window with a new window when an event occurs (such as a button click).
An answer to a similar question here [Replace CentralWidget in MainWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550076/replace-centralwidget-in-mainwindow), suggests using QStackedWidgets but they did not use Qt Designer to make their GUI apps whereas I have two .py files, one is the main window file and the other of window that i want to show after a button press take place, hence i don't know how to combine these two in my main.py file.
For Example my main window looks like this:
[image: Main Window]
And after clicking on the button it should replace the existing window with this:
[image: New Window]
I would also like to know if the second window should be of type QStackedWindow, QDialog or QWidget?
Here is my main.py code

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys
import design, design1
import os

class ExampleApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ExampleApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btnBrowse.clicked.connect(self.doSomething)


    def doSomething(self):
        # Code to replace the main window with a new window
        pass


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = ExampleApp()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to actually create and delete a bunch of windows, but if you really want to, you could do it like this

```
def doSomething(self):
    # Code to replace the main window with a new window
    window = OtherWindow()
    window.show()
    self.close()
```

The in the `OtherWindow` class

```
class OtherWindow(...):
    ...
    def doSomething(self):
        window = ExampleApp()
        window.show()
        self.close()
```

You actually probably don't want to do this.  It would be much better if you simply created 1 main window, with a `QStackedWidget` and put the different controls and widgets on different tabs of the stacked widget and just switch between them in the same window.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the QStackedWindow to create a entire new window and hten connect it to the main window through onclick() event.

```
button.clicked.connect(self.OtherWindow)
```

Or else you can simply use the

```
class OtherWindow(self):
    Owindow = OtherWindow()  
    Owindow.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = ExampleApp()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why won't you close the other window?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example, you just have to use your own logistic but it's a simple way to represent what you are looking for.

You can use QWindow instead of QWidgets if your prefer, or different layout to dispose your "objects" or whatever. Maybe change a bit how to add items inside layout if not widget... things like that. :)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QStackedLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):

    front_wid = None

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        # MAIN WINDOW size
        self.setFixedSize(200,200)

        # CENTRAL WIDGET
        self.central_wid = QWidget()
        self.layout_for_wids = QStackedLayout()

        # BUTTON TO SWITCH BETWEEN WIDGETS
        self.btn_switch = QPushButton("Switch")
        self.btn_switch.clicked.connect(self.switch_wids)
        self.btn_switch.setFixedSize(50,50)
        self.btn_switch

        # 2 WIDGETS
        self.wid1 = QWidget()
        self.wid1.setStyleSheet("""background: blue;""")
        self.wid1.setFixedSize(200,200)
        self.wid1.move(100, 100)
        self.wid2 = QWidget()
        self.wid2.setStyleSheet("""background: green;""")
        self.wid2.setFixedSize(200, 200)
        self.wid2.move(100, 100)

        # LAYOUT CONTAINER FOR WIDGETS AND BUTTON
        self.layout_for_wids.addWidget(self.btn_switch)
        self.layout_for_wids.addWidget(self.wid1)
        self.layout_for_wids.addWidget(self.wid2)

        # ENTERING LAYOUT
        self.central_wid.setLayout(self.layout_for_wids)

        # CHOOSE YOUR CENTRAL WIDGET
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_wid)

        # WHICH WIDGET IS ON THE FRONT
        self.front_wid = 1

    def switch_wids(self):

        # LOGIC TO SWITCH
        if self.front_wid == 1:
            self.wid1.hide()
            self.wid2.show()
            self.front_wid = 2
        else:
            self.wid1.show()
            self.wid2.hide()
            self.front_wid = 1



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow()
    main.resize(222, 222)
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**By the way it's PyQt5, if you want to use PyQt4 you have to change the imports that's all.**